Can Firefox on Android translate a selected paragraph via a context menu?
I noticed that Firefox on desktop enables to translate a selected paragraph or just a selected word via a context menu.
I'm missing this functionality on mobile Firefox. It only enables translating the whole page. Can I enable this functionality in some settings or via addon?
